# how to deploy a custom dll along with azure function using appveyor

Tags: azure, azure-functions, appveyor

Deploying azure function using appveyor is straightforward as described by this article - https://alastairchristian.com/deploying-azure-functions-from-appveyor-75fe03771d0c#.x7stvprna

Further what I am not able to figure out is how to deploy a custom dll (library part of the same repo) in the /bin folder to be able to use #r and use the reference.

Manual process is just to copy the dll in the /bin folder using Kudu and start using it.

Also refer to this discussion on appveyor - http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/2842-deployment-to-azure-function-app

Here is my appveyor.yml -

```
    -
  branches:
    only:
      - master

  version: 0.0.{build}
  os: Visual Studio 2015
  configuration: Release
  init:
  - nuget sources update -Name nuget.org -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
  environment:
    SolutionDir: $(APPVEYOR_BUILD_FOLDER)\
  cache:
  - packages -> **\packages.config
  assembly_info:
    patch: true
    file: '**\AssemblyInfo.*'
    assembly_version: '{version}'
    assembly_file_version: '{version}'
    assembly_informational_version: '{version}'
  before_build:
  - nuget restore -verbosity detailed

  build:
    verbosity: normal
    project: MyLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj
    publish_wap: true
    publish_azure: true
    parallel: true

  artifacts:
  - path: AzureFuncCIPOC
    name: AzureFuncCIPOC

  deploy:
  - provider: WebDeploy
    server: https://functioncipoc.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=FunctionCIPOC
    website: FunctionCIPOC
    username: $FunctionCIPOC
    password:
      secure: <secure>
    artifact: AzureFuncCIPOC
```

Answer (score 2):

If your build process is building that library and moving the output (your custom DLL) so that is is packaged in the artifact created by AppVeyor, it will be deployed with the scripts.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that in this scenario

Comment: There are a few ways to accomplish that, but a post-build action/script (either as part of your project or in AppVeyor) to copy you DLL into the appropriate location in the AzureFunctionCIPOC folder should give you what you need.

Comment: Fabio, per my understanding with WebDeploy you do not have access to `bin` folder, right? I proposed some workarounds [here](http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/questions/3419-how-to-deploy-custom-dll-along-with-azure-function)

Comment: I am trying to use 7z command to make it put the dlls into the artifact but can't figure out yet how to make it get to the /<function>/bin folder within th e archive. Commands I am trying out are something like this - 
  - 7z a AzureFuncCIPOC.zip .\AzureFuncCIPOC\*
  - cd /D MyLibrary\
  - 7z a AzureFuncCIPOC.zip bin\

Comment: The `bin` folder in functions is a bit different, though, and you should be able to package that up. @Abhishek can you try just packing that file in and deploying for validation?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to copy the dlls (using project post build event) to the function/bin and deploy successfully, will post the script in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to copy the required dlls as project post-build event and then use the same .yml as posted in question to achieve what I was after. Really hope that VS 2017 will have better support for this when Azure Functions tools for VS2017 are launched.

below is the post-build event command

```
if not exist "$(SolutionDir)AzureFuncCIPOC\\ManualTriggerCSharp\bin\" mkdir "$(SolutionDir)AzureFuncCIPOC\\ManualTriggerCSharp\bin\"
copy /y "$(TargetDir)" "$(SolutionDir)AzureFuncCIPOC\\ManualTriggerCSharp\bin\"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was recommending below :)
Yes, the next version of our tooling will have some better support for this scenario.

Comment: looking forward to it!

Comment: If the answer below helped, please mark it as answer to make sure others are helped as well.